# Syntax errors when defining variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I am getting syntax errors when defining variables and I cant figure out why. I am extremely new to coding so any help is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#submitSample").click(function(){
  var fullName        = jQuery("#fullName"       ).val();
  var eMail           = jQuery("#eMail"          ).val();
  var mailingAddress  = jQuery("#mailingAddress" ).val();
  var specialRequests = jQuery("#specialRequests").val();
  var inkOne          = jQuery("#inkOne"         ).val();
  var inkTwo          = jQuery("#inkTwo"         ).val();
  var inkThree        = jQuery("#inkThree"       ).val();
  var inkFour         = jQuery("#inkFour"        ).val();
  var designOne       = jQuery("#designOne"      ).val();
  var designTwo       = jQuery("#designTwo"      ).val();
  var designThree     = jQuery("#designThree"    ).val();
  data = "fullName="         + fullName +
         "&eMail="           + eMail + 
         "&mailingAddress="  + mailingAddress +
         "&specialRequests=" + specialRequests +
         "&inkOne="          + inkOne +
         "&inkTwo="          + inkTwo +
         "&inkThree="        + inkThree  +
         "&inkFour="         + inkFour +
         "&designOne="       + designOne  +
         "&designTwo="       + designTwo +
         "&designThree="     + designThree;
  jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", 
                url: "http://www.famousartistprints.com/sample_form.php", 
                data: data, 
                success: function() {
                    jQuery("#couturePaypal").click();
                  }
    });
});
</script>
```

I opened it in Chrome and this is what I got, I am not sure what it means.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
arguments: Array[1]
0: "<"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "unexpected_token"
__proto__: Error
```

Comment: Any problem with `$` of jQuery?

Comment: I am using dreamweaver, is there a program that will give me more information? It just says syntax errors. Im using jQuery instead of $ sign because my Drupal site prefers this.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get in your console?

Comment: @Starx Which problem with `$` would ever be a syntax error?

Comment: @alex, Why are you angry with me? How can that be related to error?

Comment: Don't forget to make it sure that jQuery is loaded, by wrapping your code: `jQuery(document).ready(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, In Dreamweaver having the "script" tag automatically gives a syntax error. I feel dumb :(. Thanks for all the comments and help!

Comment: That seems remarkably unreasonable. You're saying that opening what you wrote in a browser (like Chrome) gives no errors on JavaScript console (option-command-j)?

Comment: Why would dreamweaver give syntax error on having a "script" tag?